# PHP-FPM does not start after container creation

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, fpm

I made a Dockerfile, but when I run it and enter the container, the **php8.0-fpm service is not running**.

How do I make it run at build time? Note that I run the command `service php8.0-fpm start` in the Dockerfile and even then it is not running.

What should I do for the php8.0-fpm service to start along with the container?

Below is the Dockerfile I made:

````
FROM ubuntu:jammy

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Instalação Apache e PHP

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install software-properties-common -y && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    apache2 \
    libapache2-mod-php8.0 \
    libapache2-mod-php \
    php8.0-fpm \
    libapache2-mod-fcgid \

# Alteração sequência index

COPY /src/dir.conf /etc/apache2/mods-enabled

# Commitando a nova configuração

RUN service apache2 restart
RUN service php8.0-fpm restart

# Inserindo página info.php

COPY /src/info.php /var/www/html

# Alterando módulos de multiprocessamento

RUN service apache2 stop && \
    a2dismod php8.0 && \
    a2dismod php8.1 && \
    a2dismod mpm_prefork && \
    a2enmod mpm_event && \
    a2enconf php8.0-fpm && \
    a2enmod proxy && \
    a2enmod proxy_fcgi && \
    service apache2 restart && \
    service php8.0-fpm start

# Entrypoint para o conteiner iniciar o Apache

ENTRYPOINT ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to leave it in just one container, PHP has an extension called Supervisor and with it installed we were able to start two or more services inside the container.

The Dockerfile looked like this:

```
FROM httpd:2.4-alpine

RUN apk update && \
    apk add \
    php \
    php-fpm \
    php-zip \
    composer \
    supervisor

COPY . /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
COPY httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
COPY supervisor /etc/supervisor

WORKDIR /usr/local/apache2/htdocs

CMD ["supervisord","-n", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
```

And I created two configuration files for Supervisor.

**apache.conf**

```
[program:apache]
command=httpd -DFOREGROUND
autostart=true
autorestart=true
priority=10
startretries=1
startsecs=1
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

**fpm.conf**

```
[program:php-fpm]
command = php-fpm8 --nodaemonize 
autostart=true
autorestart=true
priority=5
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

With that the two services started and it is working perfectly!

Comment: supervisor ended up being my solution as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run php fpm on startup. if you installed bash in your vm os, you can do it this way.

```
STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "php-fpm8 && include your apache here"]
```

Full guide: [How to setup PHP 8, NGINX and PHP-FPM with docker](https://www.reviewcurious.com/how-to-setup-php-8-nginx-php-fpm-and-alpine-with-docker/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A Docker container only runs a single process.  It doesn't "run services" *per se*.  The image build doesn't preserve any running processes either.  When you start the container, the image's `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` is the only thing that will be running in the container.

Avoiding the technical reasons, I'd broadly suggest that commands like `service` or `systemctl` just don't work in Docker.  `RUN service php8.0-fpm restart`, for example, does nothing: PHP-FPM wasn't running before this command, and after the `RUN` command it won't be running either.

You'd typically restructure this into multiple separate containers, using a tool like Docker Compose to run them all together.  Docker has a couple of [official sample applications](https://docs.docker.com/samples/) that demonstrate this.  A Compose-based setup for this might look like

```yaml
# docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  php:
    build: .  # using default Dockerfile
  apache:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.apache
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
```

Your `Dockerfile` would begin `FROM php:8.0-fpm` and contain only the PHP-related setup; `Dockerfile.apache` would begin `FROM httpd:2.4` and only copy in the static assets and Apache configuration.  Your proxy setup would need to reference the other container by name `ProxyPass "/" "fcgi://php:9000"`; see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation for additional details.

Note that, even in this case, something like `docker-compose exec apache service apache2 status` still wouldn't show "a service is running", but if you `docker-compose exec apache ps -e` you'd see the HTTP daemon as process 1 within the container.  This is normal.